# Show Google Maps using Latitude and Longitude from MSSQL database does not show

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, google-maps

I have the following markup html with javascript code

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var markers = [
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
             {
                 "title": '<%# Eval("Company") %>',
             "lat": '<%# Eval("GpsLat") %>',
             "lng": '<%# Eval("GpsLong") %>'
         }
</ItemTemplate>
<SeparatorTemplate>
    ,
</SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
];
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
            });
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.title);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
    }
</script>

         <div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px"> </div>


</form>
```

In aspx code behind, i have the code to load data from MSSQL datase

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = this.GetData("select Company,GpsLat,GpsLong from tblSuppliers");
            rptMarkers.DataSource = dt;
            rptMarkers.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private DataTable GetData(string query)
    {
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;

                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When i run the page, i only see a gray square having the With and Heigh define for the div, but i cant see the map.

NB: There is no error showing in the developer tool

How can i make the google map show ?

**Update**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var markers = [

             {
                 "title": 'Orchidée organisation',
             "lat": '5,363223100000',
             "lng": '-3,942392299999'
         }

    ,

             {
                 "title": 'Brain Corporation',
             "lat": '5,359951700000',
             "lng": '-4,008256300000'
         }

    ,

             {
                 "title": '2K event',
             "lat": '0,000000000000',
             "lng": '0,000000000000'
         }

];
</script>
```

This is the result that the asp:Repeater gives as output

**update to show the page result**

[image]

Comment: the div for the map is visible when you show the page .. or is showed in a second moment?

Comment: the div is visible, i see the square withh the gray color on the web page

Comment: Using "View Page Source" is there anything being output by the repeater? If so, I'm not sure you should be treating your lat/long values as strings since they should be float types.

Comment: @KallumTanton i updated the post to show the value of the asp:Repeater

Comment: @Djama according to the Google Maps API documentation the LatLng constructor only takes lat/long arguments as number (int, double, float) type, whereas you're supplying a string. Try removing the single quote marks from around the GpsLat and GpsLon evaluations in the repeater.

Comment: @KallumTanton the repater is bind to the datasource from code behind , so i cant remove it. but Long and lag as store in the db as numeric(18,6)

Comment: @Djama I'm refering to the output, your currently doing this: `"lng": '<%# Eval("GpsLong") %>'`, try removing those single quotes: `"lng": <%# Eval("GpsLong") %>`

Comment: remove the string mark; the page is empty meaning blank.